# Dynamically set defaultChecked with value of setState within data map with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a enable and disable toggle button on a list of rows from a data map returned from a function to fetch results from a backend

issue is i need to set `defaultChecked` to whatever value of `el.enabled` is within the map of `json` data but have been un-successful

here is what the data map looks like

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "enabled": true,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "enabled": false,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "enabled": true,
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "enabled": false,
    }
]
```

`data` is derived from below function that fetched value from API backend

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
const fetchData = async () => {
   let json = await getData();
   setData(json);
}
```

and here is the `updateToggle` function that enabled or disabled each row

```
const [statusMode, setStatusMode] = useState();

const updateToggle = async (rowID) => {
    // rowID = el.id
    const updateData = {'id': rowID}

    if ( statusMode == true ) {
      const request = await disable(updateData);
      setStatusMode(false)
    }
    
    if ( statusMode == false ) {
      const request = await enable(updateData);
      setStatusMode(true)
    }
};
```

and here is what i have that is not working but shows what am trying to achieve

```
{data.map((el, k) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={setStatusMode(el.enabled, k)} onClick={() => updateToggle(el.id, k)} />
            </label>
          </div> 
        </div>
    );
  })}
```

issue is happening right here `defaultChecked={setStatusMode(el.enabled, k)}` as i want to set the value to whatever i get from `el.enabled` for the specific row

error am getting at the moment is

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

how can i achieve this? or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You can pass the data as the initial value for `useState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing and immediately invoking the state updater function, leading to the render looping.

```
const [statusMode, setStatusMode] = useState();

{data.map((el, k) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="switch">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            defaultChecked={setStatusMode(el.enabled, k)} // <-- updates state!!
            onClick={() => updateToggle(el.id, k)}
          />
        </label>
      </div> 
    </div>
  );
})}
```

You should set the `defaultChecked` value to that of the values being mapped over. Let the `onClick` handler handle updating the state.

```
const [statusMode, setStatusMode] = useState();

{data.map((el, k) => {
  return (
    <div key={el.id}>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="switch">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            defaultChecked={el.enabled} // <-- el.enabled
            onClick={() => updateToggle(el.id, k)}
          />
        </label>
      </div> 
    </div>
  );
})}
```

#### Update

Ok, I've gathered that you:

1. Asynchronously fetch and store in state some "data".
2. You render this data into checkboxes.
3. You want to toggle the state ***and*** call some endpoints.

Code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
  const json = await getData();
  setData(json);
};

const updateToggle = async (rowID) => {
  // rowID = el.id
  const updateData = {'id': rowID}

  // find elements first
  const dataEl = data.find(el => el.id === rowID);

  // conditionally enable/disable in backend
  if (dataEl.enabled) {
    const request = await disable(updateData);
  } else {
    const request = await enable(updateData);
  }

  // update local state
  setData(data => data.map(el => el.id === rowId
    ? { ...el, enabled: !el.enabled }
    : el
  ));
};

...

{statusMode.map((el) => {
  return (
    <div key={el.id}>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="switch">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={el.enabled}
            onClick={() => updateToggle(el.id)}
          />
        </label>
      </div> 
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: will this work if `data` is also a state from a function that calls API backend? i only put how the data looks, it is not static const..it is state from a fetch function

Comment: @uberrebu Not sure I follow, but sure, it should work at least once if you are just setting the default checked value of an input. Have you missed including relevant details and code in your question? What function? What API? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I'm gathering now that `data` is asynchronously updated and you're asking how to set the defaultChecked prop after the fact?

Comment: added more details in the question...so it did get the data actually but does not work when i try to enable or disable..nothing happens...i added all the details..and the `updateToggle` function also

Comment: current issue now is the `updateToggle` function is not working at all...what am i missing there? or what do i have wrong?

Comment: @uberrebu What isn't working in that `updateToggle` function? What are those `enable`|`disable` functions doing that you're awaiting?

Comment: `enable` is the async function that calls API to set the value of `el.enabled` to true and `disable` is the async function that calls API to set the value of `el.enabled` to false

Comment: @uberrebu And what isn't working? What are you expecting? Any issues with `updateToggle` seem unrelated to your original question, BTW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236121/discussion-between-uberrebu-and-drew-reese).

Comment: the `updateToggle` is not getting called at all when i click any of the rows...so `onClick` is not working

Comment: just saw you modified your answer `const [statusMode, setStatusMode] = useState(data);` to `const [statusMode, setStatusMode] = useState();`, i never knew this, the issue here is how am i updating `setStatusMode`? that is why `updateToggle` is not working at all..there is no more state

Comment: yeah that is the problem..which is why i wanted `defaultChecked={setStatusMode(el.enabled, k)}` so i can now take over the state..but your answer does not work...there is no state in your answer..question explains that i want to setup being able click to enable and disable per row of data

Comment: ok i will have to test your answer in a bit...my answer is not able to update state per row..so has issues still

Comment: in line `#5` of your updated answer why did you change this `setData(json);` to this `setStatusMode(json);`? `setData` is how i set the state of the `data` that is used to store the json data...so was that a typo from you?

Comment: tested and worked!!! i fixed the mistakes and accepted as answer..thanks a lot..really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `enabled` data as a prop and assign it to the initial state of the component

You could see the working example here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-cookies-dn7z7?file=/src/App.js:0-873

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    enabled: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    enabled: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    enabled: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    enabled: false
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((el, k) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label class="switch">
                <SingleCheckbox singleData={el} key={el.id} />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function SingleCheckbox({ singleData }) {
  const [statusMode, setStatusMode] = useState(singleData.enabled);

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      defaultChecked={statusMode}
      onClick={() => setStatusMode(!statusMode)}
    />
  );
}
```